# Is there any method to get rid of this error. (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'customer_customerprofile.user_id'")?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have to create a field called location from the lat and on like in this program. The location is printing out correctly, but there is a duplicate entry error while saving.
I need to update the user_id to id when the post function works. Since it is saved twice, the duplicate entry error is showing.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                lat = serializer.data.get('latitude',None)
                lon=serializer.data.get('longitude',None)
                lat_1=float(lat)
                lon_1=float(lon)
                location=Point((lat_1,lon_1),srid=4326)
                print(location)
                id=serializer.data.get('user')
                print(id)
                v=CustomerProfile(location=location,user_id=id)
                v.save()
                return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
            return Response({"message":"Customer registration failed!!","data":serializer.data}, status=400)
```

User model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_service_provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    # is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone','email']
```

CustomerProfile Model

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.PointField(default=Point(0,0),geography=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(blank=True,max_digits=9,decimal_places=6,default=None,null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(blank=True,max_digits=9,decimal_places=6,default=None,null=True)
```

Comment: Please add your `CustomerProfile` and `User` models.

Comment: please have a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created new instance, instead of we get(**v=CustomerProfile.objects.get(id=id)**) this user and updated.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                lat = serializer.data.get('latitude',None)
                lon=serializer.data.get('longitude',None)
                lat_1=float(lat)
                lon_1=float(lon)
                location=Point((lat_1,lon_1),srid=4326)
                print(location)
                id=serializer.data.get('user')
                print(id)
                v=CustomerProfile.objects.get(id=id)
                v.location = location
                v.save()
                return Response({"message":"Customer Profile Updated Successfully","data":serializer.data}, status=200)
            return Response({"message":"Customer registration failed!!","data":serializer.data}, status=400)
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError at /api/customer
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte


Im getting this error.

Comment: could you please share full stack trace via pastebin